# ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

I am building a project using maven and when I try to deploy on server getting below exception. Multipart jar is already present in the maven dependencies.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: try to post more code?

Comment: This was because the maven dependency jars are not added as part of war file.

Answer (score 2):

Class not found exception means that jar file does not exist so you need to add it.Add this dependency in your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then do maven clean and install and deploy it

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dependency, `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart` add it:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar [jersey-media-multipart](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart) to your classpath.

eg: with `gradle`:

```
'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the other jar is not present in your classPath.
Try mvn install instead of mvn package

Comment: which is the other jar?

Comment: Your jersey dependency. You should verify your dependency and then do a mvn clean install